# Waiting spinning wheel shiny R

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

I'm trying to implement a spinning wheel while my chart is loading. (https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/plot-spinner)

For example purpose, I have the following code:

**ui**

```
mycss <- "
#plot-container {
position: relative;
}
#loading-spinner {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
z-index: -1;
margin-top: -33px;  /* half of the spinner's height */
margin-left: -33px; /* half of the spinner's width */
}
#plot.recalculating {
z-index: -2;
}
"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(mycss))),
  # actionButton("btn", "Plot (takes 2 seconds)"),

  div(id = "plot-container",
      tags$img(src = "spinner.gif",
               id = "loading-spinner"),
      highchartOutput("plot")
  )
)
```

**server**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {
output$plot <- renderHighchart({


  Sys.sleep(2)



  rainfall <- c(49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144, 176,
                135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4)

  temperature <- c(7, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5,
                   25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6)

  col1 <- "#90ED7D"
  col2 <- "#5C5C61"

  highchart() %>% 
    hc_title(text = "Tokyo Climate") %>% 
    hc_legend(enabled = FALSE) %>% 
    hc_xAxis(categories = month.abb) %>% 
    hc_yAxis_multiples(
      list(
        title = list(text = "Temperature"),
        align = "left",
        showFirstLabel = FALSE,
        showLastLabel = FALSE,
        labels = list(format = "{value} &#176;C", useHTML = TRUE)
      ),
      list(
        title = list(text = "Rainfall"),
        align = "right",
        showFirstLabel = FALSE,
        showLastLabel = FALSE,
        labels = list(format = "{value} mm"),
        opposite = TRUE
      )
    ) %>% 
    hc_add_series(name = "Rainfall", type = "column",
                  data = rainfall, yAxis = 1) %>% 
    hc_add_series(name = "Temperature", type = "spline",
                  data = temperature) %>% 
    hc_add_series(name = "Sunshine", type = "pie",
                  data = list(list(y = 2020, name = "Sunshine hours",
                                   sliced = TRUE, color = col1),
                              list(y = 6740, name = "Non sunshine hours (including night)",
                                   color = col2,
                                   dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE))),
                  center = c('20%', 45),
                  size = 80)
  })

})
```

and this works properly. But I want to change the ui template, to the following:

**new ui**

```
mycss <- "
.plot-container {
position: relative;
}
.loading-spinner {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
z-index: -1;
margin-top: -33px;
margin-left: -33px;
}
.plot.recalculating {
z-index: -2;
}
"


ui <-dashboardPage(skin = "black",

                   dashboardHeader(),
              dashboardSidebar(


                sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu"


                )
                ##############


              ),

              dashboardBody(

                tags$head(tags$style(HTML(mycss))),

                div(id = "plot-container",
                    tags$img(src = "spinner.gif",
                             id = "loading-spinner"),
                    highchartOutput("plot")
                )


                ))
```

Like this, the spinning wheel appears above the plot and don't disappear after the plot....

Can someone help me?

Comment: In the second ui.R you are referencing classes instead of ids. Just change the dot(.) with the hash(#).

Comment: @ValterBeaković If I do that, the wheel doesn't appear at all

Comment: There is a nice progress spinner already implemented in package shinymaterial. See https://ericrayanderson.github.io/shinymaterial/. The functions are `material_spinner_show` and `material_spinner_hide`.